# How to Target older versions of framework using VS2005?

Tags: .net, configuration, visual-studio-2005

I have VS2005 and VS2008 installed on my pc.

I have .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0, 3.0 SP2, and 3.5 SP1

I am able to selection which Framework to use in VS 2008 from the drop down window, but I'm curious how I set which framework I want to target a project for in VS 2005.  I obviously dont want to uninstall frameworks because I would still like to use VS 2008 for various target frameworks.

What I'm trying to accomplish is using VS2005 but only using available assemblies from 2.0.  But at the same time use VS2008 and whatever framework I want.

I tried looking for the answer already on SO, so if its a dup, just point me to the link.
Thanks

EDIT: Ok, based on what other people are mentioning and me digging a little deeper, it looks like it might be a specific version of the 2.0 framework.  I'm looking at the WaitHandle WaitOne function, and it was causing our appliation to crash on the customers PC's who claimed they had 2.0 installed.  We are calling handle.WaitOne(0), which if you look at the [2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone(VS.80).aspx) specification, it doesnt show that a WaitOne function with one parameter of an int.  However if I navigate to the definition, it shows up as v2.0.50727 and it compiles fine.  So I guess I need to target the specific framework (or make sure the customer has a newer .NET Framework installed)?

Also, do they have updated online msdn docs somewhere for the new versions?

Comment: We dont have enought licenses yet for everyone to move to 2008, we baught per user licenses.

Comment: WaitOne came in 2.0 SP1.

Comment: @Joe - Can you point me to where you found this, I just did some searching on msdn under the 3.5 framework and it looks like the WaitOne(int) was added in 2.0 SP2.  Just trying to verify what the correct version is

Comment: Hm.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone.aspx says SP1 under ChangeHistory.  However, under the overload for just (int) the community content states it was actually SP2 (and to use the older (millseconds, false) version)

Comment: Oh, the update I added to my post says the same as @Joe's comment - that it looks like the (int) version was added in 2.0SP2

Comment: Haha awesome, so I guess trial and error it is. Thanks for the link Joe! I upvoted your highest answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With the past few releases of Visual Studio, each Visual Studio release only supported a specific version of the .NET Framework.  For example, VS 2002 only worked with .NET 1.0, VS 2003 only worked with .NET 1.1, and VS 2005 only worked with .NET 2.0.

( From [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx) )

So I think Visual Studio 2005 will *only* do what you want. With 2008, you can select which framework to target:

```
Unfortunately the VS 2008 multi-targeting support only 
works with .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5
```

( From same article)

And finally:

> VS 2008 does run side-by-side, though,
> with VS 2005, VS 2003, and VS 2002.
> So it is definitely possible to
> continue targeting .NET 1.1 projects
> using VS 2003 on the same machine as
> VS 2008.

( From same article)

### Update:

[WaitHandle..::.WaitOne Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx) says:

> Version Information .NET Framework
> Supported in: 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP2, ***2.0 SP2***

So do you both have the same level of service pack?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated my post based on the answers and with a little more info

Comment: Yeah, I need to check with our install shield expert to see what we are actually installing.  My guess is we didnt install either SP1 or SP2

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft committed a fairly major sin when they released .NET 3.5, they changed the public interface of the WaitHandle class but did not change the [AssemblyVersion] of mscorlib.dll, it was left at version 2.0.0.0.  The added WaitHandle method was certainly important, few programmers ever guessed the proper value for the "exitContext" argument (false).  But not changing the version gave you this headache to deal with.

There is no good workaround, beyond avoiding using the new overload.  Or strongly recommending your customer to re-enable Windows Update.  Targeting a specific .NET framework version cannot work since they all got the same version of mscorlib.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Use [supportedRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think VS2005 will let you use anything *but* FX2.

And there is no need to uninstall anything.

Re the Edit:

In this specific case, you could use the `WaitOne(int, bool)` version (with `false` for the 2nd).

It is possible to derive from the docs, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone%28VS.80%29.aspx) and note the upper right corner.

But this method was added to  Fx2 **by Fx3.5**, so it does validate your question and BinkDev's answer. You need to find out the specific (minimum) version from your clients and make sure you at least run/test with that.

But as best practice, make your Clients update to Fx2SP2 at the least. I'm not sure if that solves this issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated my post based on the answers and with a little more info

Answer (score 0):

VS2005, you can change the project file and include the following in the  section.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```